# What does the -MM flag do in g++?

Tags: c++, g++

I have read the explanation on the manual page (https://linux.die.net/man/1/g++) but I still do not understand its use cases. I have seen it used in the example below:

```
g++ -MM -w --std=c++14 `pkg-config fuse3 --cflags` -fpermissive -I.. hello.cpp > .obj/hello.d
```

I would like to understand when and why it is used.

Comment: https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/languages/C-C-plus-plus/GCC/options/M/index

Comment: It is used to automatically create and keep up-to-date `Makefile` dependencies for the source files. After running the command you show, try to look at the file `.obj/hello.d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.obj/hello.d` file you obtain probably looks like this.

```
hello.o: hello.cpp something.h stuff.h ...
```

This is a dependency rule for a `makefile`.

If your `makefile` uses something like

```
-include .obj/*.d
```

then it will be the same as if you explicitly wrote these dependencies.

If a generic rule knows how to generate a `.o` from the corresponding `.cpp`, then it will be triggered everytime one of those automaticaly listed header files is changed.